# Playing sound over running sound thread, or resuming playback?

Tags: html, audio, cordova, sencha-touch, media

I have the following method to play sound in a phonegap app:

```
  if (Ext.os.is.Android) {
            var soundPath = util.phonegap.getResourcesPath() + "/sounds/1khz_1_5s.mp3";
            var restSound = new Media(soundPath,
                function () {
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            restSound.play();
        }
        else {
            new Ext.Audio({hidden:true, url:'sounds/1khz_1_5s.mp3'}).play();
        }
```

However, if Pandora or similar is playing while my app is open, this stops the audio and doesn't resume it when my sound finishes. How do I resume whatever audio was happening when I played sound?

I need this to work on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a javascript bridge. It's just easier.